# What's a good heuristic to see if a set of bytes are encoded as UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a byte stream that may be UTF-8 data or it may be a binary image.  I should be able to make an educated guess about which one it is by inspecting the first 100 bytes or so.

However, I haven't figured out exactly how to do this in Java.  I've tried doing things like the following:

new String( bytes, "UTF-8").substring(0,100).matches(".*[^\p{Print}]") to see if the first 100 chars contain non-printable characters, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

    try {
        final String s = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString();
        Log.d( s );
    } catch( CharacterCodingException e ) {
        // don't log binary data
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In well formed UTF-8 a byte with the top bit set must be either followed or preceded by another byte that has the top bit set; the first of a run must start with the two topmost bits set and the rest must have the next-to-top bit clear (in fact the first of a run of N top-bit bytes must have the top N bits set and the next one clear).

Those characteristics should be easy enough to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/)

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: This is just a pointer to a lib that could help, not a full answer. It seems legitimate though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler/cleaner version of emmby's answer, for a (possibly huge) byte stream:

```
/**
 * Determines whether the stream is valid UTF-8  
 * @param is InputStream (will be closed)
 * @return true if it's valid UTF-8 , false elsewhere
 * @throws IOException Only for other I/O problems
 */
public static boolean isUtf8(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    final int CHARS = 8192;
    final char[] cbuf = new char[CHARS];
    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, decoder)) {
        while(isr.read(cbuf) > 0) {
        }
    } catch(CharacterCodingException e) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```